# Google Analitycs Service crash

Tags: android, google-analytics

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to find app for caller android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@43d42298 (pid=819) when starting service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH cmp=com.nobelglobe.nobelapp/com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService }
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startService(ActivityManagerNative.java:3222)
at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1838)
at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1811)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:505)
at com.google.android.gms.analytics.internal.zzb.void zziL()(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics.void dispatchLocalHits()(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.analytics.ExceptionReporter.void uncaughtException(java.lang.Thread,java.lang.Throwable)(Unknown Source)
at org.acra.ErrorReporter.void endApplication(java.lang.Thread,java.lang.Throwable)(ErrorReporter.java:457)
at org.acra.ErrorReporter.java.lang.ref.WeakReference access$002(org.acra.ErrorReporter,java.lang.ref.WeakReference)(ErrorReporter.java:81)
                          android.app.Application access$400(org.acra.ErrorReporter)
                          boolean access$1102(org.acra.ErrorReporter,boolean)
                          android.content.Intent access$1200(org.acra.ErrorReporter,java.lang.String,org.acra.ErrorReporter$ReportBuilder)
                          void access$1300(org.acra.ErrorReporter,java.lang.Thread,java.lang.Throwable)
                          void access$1400(org.acra.ErrorReporter,org.acra.ErrorReporter$ReportBuilder)
at org.acra.ErrorReporter$5.void run()(ErrorReporter.java:851)
```

We have this crash in our app that has over 10000 occurrences daily. Can not be reproduced on any of the devices that we have, it is reported by the crash handler.

We have followed the basic implementation describe [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/GoogleAnalytics).

```
<!--
             Optionally, register AnalyticsReceiver and AnalyticsService to support background
              dispatching on non-Google Play devices
        -->
         <receiver
             android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
             android:enabled="true">
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH"/>
             </intent-filter>
         </receiver>


         <service
             android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
             android:enabled="true"
             android:exported="false"/>


        <!--
             Optionally, register CampaignTrackingReceiver and CampaignTrackingService to enable
             installation campaign reporting
        -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource"
            android:resource="@xml/analytics_global_config" />
```

Now, I see that the action `com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH` is used with AnalyticsService to optionally support background dispatching on non-Google Play devices, which I guess we can choose no to support and it may clear this issue.

Has anybody encountered this issue before?

Comment: `non-Google Play devices` i do not understand. which android devices running without it? wait let me check my `AnalyticsReceiver`

Comment: that's what the comment in the manifest says: <!--
             Optionally, register AnalyticsReceiver and AnalyticsService to support background
              dispatching on non-Google Play devices
        --> , see above

Comment: ya i think you're right. But still confused `which android devices running without it?`

Comment: apparently 20% of the devices which are made by chinese manufacturers: http://thenextweb.com/google/2014/08/05/google-under-threat-as-forked-android-devices-rise-to-20-of-smartphone-shipments/#gref :)

Comment: Ignore some of the devices. `it's all an exceptions`